# How to refresh a ListView when I delete all SQLite table data in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have a listview with elements coming from a SQLite table, when I delete the contents of the table and try to refresh the listview I get a null exception

I do the following

```
mHelper.clearDatabase("TableName");
Adapter.clear();
Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

public void clearDatabase(String TABLE_NAME) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String clearDBQuery = "DELETE FROM "+TABLE_NAME;
    db.execSQL(clearDBQuery);
}
```

How I am going to refresh my listview from a table which contains nothing?

The message from LogCat

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.computergr.contacts, PID: 15356
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'void com.computergr.contacts.model.SettingsGameCursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()' on a null object reference 
at com.computergr.contacts.Settings$7.onClick(Settings.java:354)
at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:157)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: We need the logcat guys to see what causes NPE.

Comment: Okay. Can you post code where you initialize and setting `Adapter`.

Comment: Call your Adapter code in OnResume Method then after run For Example:- lv.setAdapter(adapter); call this in OnResume method.

Comment: Can you show us where you firstly set your adapter?

Answer (score 0):

I think I should put something like

Adapter = new SettingsCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),AllContacts); before I call 
Adapter.swapCursor(AllContacts);